# How to preserve the content flow following an absolutely positioned image?

Tags: html, css

Strangely, I could not find anything when I googled this issue.

I have a bunch of images stacked on top of each other (not vertically), using `position: absolute`.

So the HTML basically looks like this:

```
<div class="image-gallery">
  <img src="whatever.jpg">
  <img src="whatever2.jpg" class="hidden">
  <img src="whatever3.jpg" class="hidden">
</div>
```

And the CSS to make them both stack and be responive but keep their aspect ratio:

```
.image-gallery {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.image-gallery img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

That all work fine, but the problem is the content coming after this gallery. It lies on top of it, because the images don't take up any space so far as the HTML is concerned.

Is there a simple CSS fix to preserve the content flow or do I have to set the `height` of the containing div to a fraction of the `width` using a JavaScript resize function or something?

**JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/01xoet16/**

Comment: Are those images same size?

Comment: @Pangloss They could be forced to be if it makes things simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to **Quentin**'s great explanation. I'm suggesting a workaround here. So looks like you can leave one of the image not to be absolute, so the space is always reserved, and play with `z-index` if necessary.

The solution only works if all the images are the same size.

http://jsfiddle.net/01xoet16/3/

```
.image-gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.image-gallery img.hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Extra controls with `z-index`.

http://jsfiddle.net/01xoet16/4/

```
.image-gallery img:not(.hidden) {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.image-gallery img.hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple CSS fix to preserve the content flow

No. Absolute positioning removes content from normal flow. Such content cannot influence the position of other (non-descendant) elements.

> or do I have to set the height of the containing div to a fraction of the width using a JavaScript resize function or something?

That or know what dimensions your images are going to be in the first place.

Alternatively, consider hiding the images by toggling their `display` property (which leaves them in normal flow when visible) instead of absolutely positioning them.

Comment: Yes, I think I left `position: absolute` from when I considered manipulating `z-index` instead of simply hiding them. Doh!